# Clash between relation id column and similar column name on table for model with `belongs_to` definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I am using Rails 3 and trying to set up an association with a model called `Reseller` on a model called `Company`.

I also have a boolean field called `reseller`.

Therefore, the table `companies` has the columns `reseller:boolean` and `reseller_id:integer`.

I am getting an error when I have `form_fields` for these two column in my view:

`undefined method 'to_i' for "#<Reseller:0x007fc081e3cfa8>":Reseller`

The error is occurring where I expect the reseller:boolean field to be handled: `<%= c.check_box :reseller  %>` and not the Reseller association.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the moment you put

```
belongs_to :reseller
```

in you Company model, you got a conflict, since this will create reseller method for your association.

solution is to rename your boolean, or your association. You can also do the latter without changing the db:

```
belongs_to :company_reseller, :foreign_key => :reseller_id
```